# Predicate Logic and CNF

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, predicate, conjunctive-normal-form

One given example, two questions, two ideas:

```
∃t ∀s learn(s, t, a) and not distracted(s) => passExam(s, a)
```

1) What means that in natural language?

There is a t(opic), when a s(tudent) learns that t(opic) in a(rtificial intelligence) and is not distracted, this s(tudent) pass the exam in a(i)

2) What is the CNF of it?

```
not learn(G(x), F(x)) or distracted(G(x)) or passExam(G(x), a)
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It greatly depends how the functions and variables are defined, but I'll assume `learn(a,b,c) := a learns topic b in area c` and the other 2 defined as per what would be assumed. You basically have it right, you just forgot the `and aren't distracted`:

"There exists a topic such that all students who learn this topic in Artificial Intelligence and aren't distracted will pass the Artificial Intelligence exam."

2) [... all disjunctions of literals are in CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). So this means the example is already in CNF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in the example we have ``learn(s, t, a) and not distracted(s)`` and an implication as well as two quantors. They should be eliminated (Skolemization), I thought.

Comment: @MichaelDorner I'm not too familiar with Skolemization, but the way I see it, it converts `there exists` to `get the one that exists`, which doesn't really seem to apply in this case.